# How do I convert my class and render() to a functional component using react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

I'm trying to convert my class to a functional component but I'm having trouble with the `isInputActive`. This is what the class looks like:

**BEFORE**

```
class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          isInputActive: false,
        };
      }

render() {
    const focusHandler = () => {
      onChange('');
      this.setState({
        isInputActive: true,
      });
    };
```

And in my `return()`, I've got this:

```
<input
  onBlur={() => {
  this.setState({ isInputActive: false });
  }}
 />
```

So, I tried converting it as seen below:

I converted the class to a const:

**AFTER**

```
const HelloWorld = ({ isInputActive }) => {
  const [isInputActive, setIsInputActive] = useState(false);
```

Then my `render()` was converted as seen here:

```
const focusHandler = () => {
    onChange('');
    setIsInputActive(true);
  };
```

And finally, I assumed that my `<input>` in the `return()` would look like this (the `setState` became `useState` which I'm not sure if it's correct either):

```
onBlur={() => {
 useState({ isInputActive: false });
  }}
```

Does anyone know what it should look like? to make it work without erroring? Where I've done
`const PinInput = ({ isInputActive }) => {`
I get an error: `Parsing error: Identifier 'isInputActive' has already been declared`

My code might be wrong so you can ignore the **AFTER** if you want. I'm just trying to make sure I get rid of the render().

Comment: You've declared a state with `useState` but used again. Just use `setIsInputActive(false);`.

Comment: I changed this: const [isInputActive, setIsInputActive] = useState(true); to useState(false) because I realised that this makes more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change,

```
onBlur={() => {
 useState({ isInputActive: false });
}}
```

**To,**

```
onBlur={() => {
 setIsInputActive(false);
}}
```

Reason you are getting this error, `Parsing error: Identifier 'isInputActive' has already been declared` is because, You are already declaring the variable `isInputActive` here,

```
const [isInputActive, setIsInputActive] = useState(true);
```

And it already hold the value of `true`.

To make it false just do `setIsInputActive(false)` ..

Comment: Is there a way for me to get rid of this: const [isInputActive, setIsInputActive] = useState(true);  And simply, have it here: const HelloWorld = ({ isInputActive }) => { but then what would the original render() look like?

Comment: @HelloL, I didn't get your use case in class component because you have nowhere called the function ```focusHandler``` from your code.. Can you make a codesandbox in class component and mention what are you trying to achieve so that it would be easy to convert to functional component..

Comment: ah nevermind, I think your solution worked but my test is failing because it fails to set the field state isInputActive to false onBlur. Are you sure that my onBlur is correct? I also switched the const [isInputActive, setIsInputActive] = useState(true); to const [isInputActive, setIsInputActive] = useState(false); so the default is false.

Comment: @HelloL, It is working fine here https://codesandbox.io/s/function-component-with-usestate-forked-9gifr .. Based on your comment **I also switched the const [isInputActive, setIsInputActive] = useState(true); to const [isInputActive, setIsInputActive] = useState(false); so the default is false.** , I have also changed the code accordingly..

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try replacing your code like this:


import React from "react";

function HelloWorld() {
  
  const [isInputActive, setIsInputActive] = React.useState(true);

  return (
    <>
      <input
        onBlur={() => {
          setIsInputActive(false);
         }}
        />
    </>
  );
}
```